# Proving an inequality about the deviation of the mean from the median

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics, lp-spaces

Let X  be a random variable with a median $m$ and mean $\mu$. I should prove that :

$$0.5||X-\mu||_p \leq ||X-m||_p\leq 3||X-\mu||_p$$

I am trying to prove that:

$$||\mu-m||_p \leq ||X-m||_p$$

By the following claim:

$$\left|\left|m-\mu\right|\right|_{p}=\left|\left|E\left[m-X\right]\right|\right|_{p}\leq E\left[\left|\left|m-X\right|\right|_{p}\right]=\left|\left|m-X\right|\right|_{p}$$

The inequality follows from Jensen's and the fact that the norm is convex.

The question :

1. Is the argument valid?
2. Does anyone know what I can do on the second part? I tried to follow a similar argument but got a scalar of 2 instead of 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X\in L_p(\mathbb{P})$, $p\geq1$,  and let $\mu_X=\mathbb{E}[X]$. For any median $m$ of $X$, showing that
$$|m-\mu_X|\leq\|X-m\|_p$$
is just an application of Hölder's inequality:
\begin{align}
|m-\mu_X|\leq\mathbb{E}\big[|X-m|\big]\leq\|X-m\|_p\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}

Often, this bound is not optimal. Another rather well known and useful relationship between the  mean and a median is:
\begin{align}
|\mu_X-m|\leq \sqrt[p]{2}\|X-\mu_X\|_p\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}

To see that, notice that if $m=\mu_X$ then the statement  holds trivially. On the other hand, if $m\neq\mu_X$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{|m-\mu_X|^p}{2}&\leq|m-\mu_X|^p\min\{\mathbb{P}[X\geq m],\mathbb{P}[X\leq m]\}\\
&\leq
|m-\mu_X|^p\Pr\big[|X-\mu_X|\geq|m-\mu_X|\big]\leq\|X-\mu_X\|^p_p
\end{align*}

Putting things together
$$|\mu_X-m|\leq\min\big(\sqrt[p]{2}\|X-\mu_X\|_p,\|X-m\|_p\big)$$

Comment: Thanks! Though I am not sure I understand who is $q$ when using Hölder's inequality, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Eilon96: $$\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1} |X|]\leq \Big(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}^q]\big)^{1/q}\big(\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]\big)^{1/p}=1\cdot \big(\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]\big)^{1/p}=\|X\|_p$$

Comment: The answer is perfect, but I can't upvote before having 15 reputations :(

Comment: @Eilon96: Oh! well, hopefully soon that will not be an impediment. Thanks! I am glad things are settled with this problem now.